# bigold look over here, how to post a json file within some special character to a URL using shell

Tags: shell, curl

i have a json to post somewhere,
the json like below: (first answer is demo detail)

```
{
  attr1: 11111111111111,
  attr2: 'markdown',
  attr3: { attr4: '!@#$%^&*()~!@#$%^&*' }
}
```

watch out,the sttr4 is not fixed,but include some special character

i attempt to use shell like this

```
var="!@#$%^&*~!@#$%^&"
curl http://localhost:3001 -d  "{\"attr1\":1,\"attr2\":\"2\",\"attr3\":{\"attr4\":\"$var\"}}"
```

but post failed,throw a error tip said the attr4 has special character,
and i also try to use --data-urlencode ,but i don't know how to convert such json format...

Answer (score 0):

**demo**:

*haha.sh file*

```
findNotLockedVersion=$(grep -Ei "@hello-world/.+([\^\>\=\<\~\|x\*|]+|[\\\"']\s+|''|\"\"|latest)" ./haha.txt )
detail="'$findNotLockedVersion'"
if [ -n "$findNotLockedVersion" ]; then
  expWarning="##### <font color='warning'>请注意：分支@hello-world/*有非固定版本写法！～</font>\n$detail...\n\n"
fi
curl  http://localhost:3001/haha -X POST -d "{\"attr1\":111,\"attr2\":\"222\",\"attr3\":{\"attr4\":$detail}}" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

*haha.txt file*

"@hello-world/xxxxx":"^4.7.0"

launch a http server, and execute haha.sh